# Rotated ggplot when coord_flip has already been used

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have the following plot produced using `ggplot2` (see http://paleoecologie.umontreal.ca/684-2/)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(neotoma)
library(analogue)

suze <- get_site(sitename = 'Le Grand Etang%')
suze_pollen=get_dataset(suze)
suze_data=get_download(suze_pollen)
core.pct <- data.frame(tran(suze_data[[1]]$counts, method = 'percent'))
age <- suze_data[[1]]$sample.meta$age
core.pct <- chooseTaxa(core.pct, max.abun = 10) 
df=data.frame(yr=rep(age,ncol(core.pct)),
 per=as.vector(as.matrix(core.pct)),
 taxa=as.factor(rep(colnames(core.pct),each=nrow(core.pct))))

ggplot(df)+
 geom_line(aes(yr,per))+
 geom_area(aes(yr,per))+
 scale_x_reverse(breaks =seq(0,100000,1000))+
 scale_y_continuous(breaks =seq(0,100,10))+
 xlab("Age (cal. BP)")+ylab("%")+
 coord_flip()+
 facet_grid(~df$taxa,scales = "free", space = "free")
```

How do I get this plot but rotated so that species are stacked along the vertical (y) axis and Age is along the horizontal axis? I cannot use `coord_flip` as it has already been used during the `ggplot` call.

Comment: To get the species along the y-direction, you could use `facet_grid(df$taxa ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free")`. To flip the `Age` and `%` axes, you could leave out the `coord_flip()`. Does that get you anywhere?